# Not able to call my express backend middleware application using Polymer iron ajax

Tags: node.js, express, polymer

I am new to polymer and express and i have started building an application i am using polymer as front end and express as the backend which is acting as middleware for security , i am making iron ajax calls on various events
a sample ajax call is

```
   <iron-ajax
   id="ajax"
 url="https://web-ui-hello.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/web/ui/api/getMapData"
 params='{"type":"all"}'
 handle-as="json"
 content-type="application/json"
 method="GET"
 on-response="helloResponse"
 debounce-duration="3000">
```

this ajax call is hitting my microservice in the backend   but when i check in the  express that i am only using as a middleware for adding some security token, i could not find this api hitting my express my app.js of this api is

```
 app.get ('/web/ui/api/getMapData',function(req,res){
 console.log('inside map');
  });
```

Can anyone help in this , i am stuck on this trying to figure out why it's not hitting express?

Comment: `404 Not Found: Requested route ('web-ui-hello.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io') does not exist.` Make sure you can access the base url first.

Comment: @Ofisora: this is the  dummy url i have given, i am able to access the original url

Comment: Any errors you get in console?

Comment: @Ofisora no i am not getting any errors in console, i just want to confirm, i am new to expressjs, do i have to add this route in a separate js  file in route folder and then  export it and then use in app.js? or what i am doing above is  fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, your Express app being a middleware needs to manipulate the request/response sent to predix.

So, instead of your web client, directly, calling the predix API, alter your client code to make request to your own server. Alter request, if any, and then initiate a new request from server to predix. Get the response of this new request, and alter it, if any. This new response should be sent as response of your original request from web client.

WebClient ----(req1)-->ExpressServer ---(req2)--->Predix

WebClient <---(res1)---ExpressServer <--(res2)----Predix